# memory leak strtok & atof

Tags: c++, valgrind, strtok, atof

```
int fromVectoEigen(vector<string> & source, double ** & array, int & n)
{  
    cout<<"n:"<<n<<'\n';
    int counter = 0;

    for (int j = n-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--) // iterate through each line
    {
        string mystring = source.back(); // take last line

        counter++;
        char * str = new char [mystring.length()+1];
        std::strcpy (str, mystring.c_str()); // copy string to char array
        char * pch; // pointer to tokens
        pch = strtok (str," ,-");
        for( int i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++) // dismiss first 3 columns
        {

            pch = strtok (NULL, " ,-");
        }

        for (int i= 0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            double val = atof(pch); // cast char to double

            //array[j][i]= val;
            //cout<<array[j][i]<<'\t';
            //pch = strtok (NULL, " ,-");
        }
        //
        //source.pop_back();

        }

    return 0;
}
```

Hey!

With this function I want to read in a matrix from file to an twodimensional array
The matrix has as many lines as columns. And i want to split the lines by space with strtok.
The lines were already read into a vector in another function.(which worked - itested it). So I dont know the Problem because I tried to run this with a small matrix 4 columns 4 lines, which worked perfectly! Now I wanted to try it with a big matrix which has over 1000 lines and as many columns. and I get this error message from valgrind:

> Invalid read of size 1
>   ==26501==    at 0x58A87AB: *_*_strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:538)
>   ==26501==    by 0x4015BB: fromVectoEigen(std::vector >&, double**&, int&) (topo.cpp:70)
>   ==26501==    by 0x40362B: main (main.cpp:36)
>   ==26501==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

I tried the comment/uncomment method and everything works fine up to where i use atof....which I dont understand cause it worked fine with the small matrix

The values in the big matrix look like this: 0.11991517 where as in the small test matrix I only had values like  0 or 0.1

I hope I explained enough...pls ask for more detail if needed.

Comment: Hey ... are you sure you have the 4th column ? strtok may return NULL if you're past the last token. (it's not safe to trust that there are n tokens, you can double check and see if there really are enough)

Comment: Also, in the second for loop, assuming n is correct and you have the same number of columns and rows, your for should go up to n-3 (because you have already skipped 3)

Comment: yes the thing is that it all works fine for one test file but just not for the other. yes i know that i already skipped three. this is an option for when there are 3 columns of description before the matrix starts ( but i commented this)

Comment: Looks like you're doing everything right, except that you don't check your assumptions (like a valic `pch` pointer). I bet you'll find that `pch` is zero if you print it. Real programmers use `assert` a lot :-)

Comment: yes thanks that was it! i changed it to a while ( pch != NULL)

Answer (score 3):

You allocate `str`, but you never free it ... and with the code you have, you never can.  Thus, every time you call this function, you will leak memory.

You should either add a `delete [] str;` when you are done with it, or don't use dynamic memory at all and stick with `std::string`.

Additionally, you can avoid the whole conversion issue and just use `std::istream::operator>>` (e.g. using `std::istringstream`) to parse your input.

Something like this (untested) should work better for you:

```
struct reader : std::ctype<char>
{
    reader() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());
        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['-'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc[' '] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['\t'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

int fromVectorEigen(const std::vector<std::string>& source, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& destination)
{
    reader rdr;
    std::for_each(source.rbegin(), source.rend(), [&](const std::string& s)
    {
        std::istringstream iss(s);
        iss.imbue(std::locale(), &rdr);
        std::string ignored_columns;
        double value;
        iss >> ignored_columns >> ignored_columns >> ignored_columns;
        std::vector<double> values;
        while (iss >> value)
        {
            values.push_back(value);
        }
        destination.push_front(values);
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And instead of using raw pointers and `delete`, assigning allocated memory to `unique_ptr`/`auto_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: That would be `delete[] str` no?

Comment: @Quirliom Yes, it would be `delete []`.  The better solution is not not use (manual) dynamic memory at all, though.

Comment: 'code'the delete[] str didnt work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with this current design of not using streams, but eliminate the explicit allocation of memory, you could use a std::vector:

```
  #include <vector>
  //...
  std::vector<char> str(mystring.begin(), mystring,end());
  str.push_back(0);
  char * pch; // pointer to tokens
  pch = strtok (&str[0]," ,-");
```